# Could not load file or assembly in github project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget, asp.net-identity

I am working on a project in a group using github, it's an asp.net mvc project. No one else in my group has problems with this but when I try to run the server to the main page of our site I get the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I've tried installing each package that comes up like this in Nuget but some of the files do not seem to be packages or have an obvious package name. I've tried using the package manager to install these packages as well and that doesn't seem to work either. Deleting the entire project and recloning it does not work nor does re installing visual studio. Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your nuget cache and delete package folder content. Close visual studio and try installing this again from package manager.

Comment: Doing this and then cleaning solution, closing visual studio and then opening and rebuilding worked for me (for now). Thanks.